# How to update the anchor link text in rich text field using Sitecore Powershell?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I would like to update the anchor link text, if the anchor link Href match with particular domain/url. Do we have any sitecore powershell script to update the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written this script by using this example.

This is my `Sitecore` item with an `RTE` field and some anchor tags.

[image]

Now, this is the script I used, and if you want you can modify this as per your needs.

```
# Get your item here by providing ID
$rootItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{56305117-8C9C-4C08-96D5-BB97A8E27419}"

# Regex pattern to check if the value contains any anchor
$anchorTagPattern = '(?is)<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>';

# Get your RTE Field 
$richTextContent = $rootItem.Fields["DB"].Value;

# Match parttern with your RTE field value
$anchorTagPatternMatches = [regex]::Matches($richTextContent, $anchorTagPattern);

# If Pattern matches 
if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($anchorTagPatternMatches)) {

# Create a loop and it will give you all the anchors in your RTE
ForEach ($patterns in $anchorTagPatternMatches) {

    # Check if anchor contains the text you want (mention your text)
    if($patterns -like '*testlink*')
    {
       
        # Keep that anchor in new variable by replacing text with your new value
        $newValue = $patterns -replace "testlink", "newLink"
        
        # Replace this new anchor with old anchor in your RTE field 
        $richTextContent = $richTextContent.Replace($patterns,$newValue);
       
        # Update your RTE with new value
        $rootItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
        $rootItem.Fields["DB"].Value = $richTextContent;    
        $rootItem.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
}
```

And the output is this. It has updated two anchors that match my value.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sumit, This is something I have expected. I will check on my end. Thanks.

Comment: @Astle Please accept the answer if this resolves your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script to update `href` value in Sitecore `rich text` field. In below powershall script I replaced value in `Multi-Line Text` field. I replaced `ifarme` from `object`.

```
$root = gi master:// -id "{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}"
$items = $root | Get-ChildItem -r | ForEach-Object{$item = $_; $_.Fields  | ?{$_.TypeKey -eq "Multi-Line Text"} }
foreach($i in $items){
   
  
   if ($i.Value -Like '*iframe*' -or $i.Value -Like '*src*') 
   {
         $replaced = $i.Value -replace 'iframe', 'object'
          $replaced = $replaced -replace 'src', 'data'
        $i.Item.Editing.BeginEdit()
  
    $i.Item.Fields[$i.Name].Value = $replaced
    $i.Item.Editing.EndEdit()
    Write-Host $i.Item.Name  "-Test"  $i.Name
    # Write-Host $i.Item.Name  "Test"  $i.Name
   }
   
}

 

Write-Host "Updated " $count " Found Values"
```

Comment: Hi @Rishiraj, Thanks for your reply. Some rich text field might have multiple anchor links and different Href. In that scenario, I have to replace particular anchor link text which is matched to the particular domain.

Comment: how many domains you have, if you have only two or three in that case you can add conditions according to domain name and then replace value.   

if($i.Value -Like '*http://domain1.com*') {
            $replaced = $i.Value -replace 'http://domain1.com', 'object'
       }
       
       if($i.Value -Like '*http://domain2.com*') {
            $replaced = $i.Value -replace 'http://domain2.com', 'object1'
       }

Comment: Hi @Rishiraj, It is not countable. Replace query we need to do for particular anchor tag. Because sometimes same content/icon we have for all anchors.